# Is binding a service to $scope a good idea?

Tags: angularjs

I have a couple of controllers page1Ctrl, page2Ctrl, etc.  and one service PriceCalculator.

The service has a couple of functions like totalPrice(productId, customerType) and others.
As i use the same service in all controllers i was thinking of using the following code:

```
app.controller('page1Ctrl', function($scope, PriceCalculator) {

    $scope.PriceCalculator = PriceCalculator;
    $scope.products = ....
...
}
```

In my page i would have then:

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="product in products">
 ...
<div>Total price: {{ PriceCalculator.totalPrice(product.id, customerType) }}</div>
```

My question is: Is it good practice to bind a service to the scope and use it from there?
What we see often is:

```
$scope.totalPrice = function(productId){
    return PriceCalculator.totalPrice(productId, ... );
}
```

Opinions? Reasons?

Comment: generally its a bad practice to bind a service to a scope.. especially if you want to unit test the controller itself... but in practice its allowed, especially if you don't want to inject the service into every child controller, its kinda cheating the system.

Comment: If totalPrice is only used in presentation layer, make it a directive to save the keystrokes and increase readability.  However, if you need totalPrice anywhere inside your scope for downstream calculations, (e.g. calculateTax()) you'll end up calling totalPrice() in your controller anyway, and all the savings from calling PriceCalculator in your view becomes duplication and opportunity for error.

Comment: thx for pointing out i should rather create a directive. On the other hand, the directive would need to inject the service there as well. Of course if i would display more than just the plain value, a directive would totally make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are seeking to follow best practices closely, then you should follow this one "The controller should be responsible for updating your view". And the service should not be exposed to the view. so something like this.

```
   app.controller('page1Ctrl', function($scope, PriceCalculator) {

     $scope.priceCalculator = function (param1, param2){
        return  PriceCalculator.totalPrice (param1, param2); 

     }


  <div>Total price: {{ priceCalculator(product.id, customerType) }}</div>
```

Otherwise, if you want something that just works fine, then you can go with your approach.

Comment: Thx, i'm aware of that. I was just doing this so far. It's more that i had the feeling in some situations that doing this somewhat useless code over and over again. clearly in controversy to DRY.

Comment: I personally go with DRY over "best practice" in this situtation--I do bind the services to `$scope`.